# How to paginate in grid/table column wise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

How to paginate in grid/table column wise?

I am trying to paginate in a grid column wise not row wise(Like we usually perform in dataTable plugin).

I am looking to paginate like this, http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried and why it did not work. [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Okey Boss...!! Thanks for correcting me. Will keep this in mind and also will always first create small POC.